# Windows application - Just Starting

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, xaml, windows

I am planing to make an windows app and I don't know where to start, which it's the best language for succeeding this.

My goal it's the following :

- an app for windows with an UI that I can customize however I want
- the app must be able to use very big database , because the plans for my app will that it will have something like 500 000 entries each day.
- the app must be able to connect with different other hardware like : thermal printer, laser printer, barcode scanner etc.

I did already programed in PHP and i am still doing it so I know some principles, I use PHP with HTML, JS, CSS and MySQL or MSSQL.

Can someone give an idea from where should i start and with what?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with C# language, which is one of the languages in `.Net framework`.

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx) for how to create a simple Windows application.

Then you can get known to .Net framework, on which Windows apps rely here, [this](http://mottishaked.com/training/dot-net-tutorial) is a really great video tutorial if you are a beginner.

Then for databases and other things [here](https://www.google.am/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwxt2cwcc.aspx&ei=5z30U9jaF4ao4gSi_4CAAQ&usg=AFQjCNGVFGRo4p-jSL20VWYzu9-h8KVM4g&cad=rja) is another article which shows you how connect your data to application.

Or you can choose WPF ( Windows Presentation Foundation) depending on what kind of program you are going to develop.

[Here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/) is a tutorial for WPF.

Start with these things, and you can make your program successfully :)

Comment: It's Visual Studio free version enough ?

Comment: I don't think so. The free(express edition) is not good for large projects.

Comment: Or you can try torrent ) And if the answer helps you, mark it as answered, for that other people can know the right answer.

Comment: It;s really helpfull the answer. Thank you verry much.